# How do I get the Facebook ID number for a large number of people? Cordova with Appavailability

Tags: facebook, cordova

I am trying to get the facebook id for a large number of people.  I can do it using a site like http://findmyfbid.com/ which is great to get one, but I need to get it for several hundred.

This is for an app, I am using cordova, and I am trying to get the appavailability plugin to work so that when someone clicks on a facebook link it will open the link in the facebook app instead of a browser.  The plugin works great, but if I use the link as facebook.com/username, it will open the facebook app but just to my personal feed.  If I use facebook.com/(facebook id number), it will open correctly to the the user's page.

I think my solution is to be able to get the id's for everyone and just use those as a link.  It would be fine if I could get the username link to work somehow with appavailability.   I am using the code from this question: [How to open Twitter and Facebook app with Phonegap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23095906/how-to-open-twitter-and-facebook-app-with-phonegap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That other website is scraping the user profiles, which is not allowed on Facebook. In fact, there is no legal way to get the ID of a user anymore, you only get one by authorizing a user, and it will only be an "App Scoped ID". There is no use for the "global ID" anymore, you should only use the App Scoped ones. Which means, what you are trying to do is not allowed.

Btw, you are not supposed to use those IDs for anything anyway, it would be a privacy issue if each single user did not specifically authorize you to get his ID (by authorizing an App).